# Sonarqube API is working with any random value in the HTTPHeader "X-Forwarded-Login"

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I'm testing sonarqube web api in my local deployment. To enforce authentication I enabled "Force user authentication" in security preferences and changed `sonar.web.sso.enable=true` in sonar.properties file.

After enabling I created an auth token for admin user and added the same token in `HTTPHeader` "`X-Forwarded-Login`" for the web api. But when tested the sonar server returns the response for any random value set to the "`X-Forwarded-Login`" header.

My need is to return response only with valid authtoken.

How to validate properly with only with valid auth tokens? I'm testing with version 6.4.

Comment: Do your request succeed, if you do not set the "X-Forwarded-Login" http header at all?

Comment: No. If I don't set the header then the request fails.

Answer (score 2):

The `X-Forwarded-Login` header and `sonar.web.sso.enable=true` are telling to SonarQube to not do any authentication but trust the reverse proxy in front of SonarQube.

The reverse proxy in front of SonarQube has the responsibility to check/authenticate (or redirect to a third party authentication service) the user and send the request of the user by adding the headers to SonarQube:

- X-Forwarded-Name
- X-Forwarded-Login
- X-Forwarded-Email
- X-Forwarded-Groups

If you just want to use token, just remove `sonar.web.sso.enable=true`, create a token with your user (using the native SonarQube authentication) and then use the token in the http header field  `login` to provide the token in your HTTP request.

You will find the documentation here : https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Token